# Very much? What?

Tags: adverbs

In this sentence:

> The air force and navy were modernized but the army, **very much** the poor relation, was not.

The "very much" used here seems to be different from the "very much" of "thank you very much". I just don't understand! What is the part of speech of "very much in the first example? Is it an adverb, or what? Please explain...

Answer (score 2):

"Very much" is a double intensifier.  When you say "thank you very much," you're saying that you not only have gratitude, you have quite a bit of gratitude, a lot more than the ordinary amount.

A poor relation is one who gets short-changed and ignored.  Someone who is very much a poor relation is not only ignored, but ignored in more than the ordinary way.  In your example sentence, the air force and the navy got a lot of money to make their forces up to date.  But the army didn't get much budget at all.

Comment: So do you mean the "very much" in each sentence above functions as a double intensifier?

Comment: Right.  "Much" mean a great amount; "very much" is even more than that.

Answer (score 2):

> *The air force and navy were modernized but the army, very much the poor relation, was not.*
>   What is the part of speech of "very much ...?  Is it an adverb,

It is an adverb. We can add an extra word to show why:

*The air force and navy were modernized but the army, [being] very much the poor relation, was not.*

'very much' modifies the deleted present participle 'being'.

Comment: Oh thank you! But I want ask is it normal that there are always cases in English writing that some word is missing? In this case, it is *being*. Then is it because the writer has bad grammar? Or do we just add the word to better understand the sentence?

Comment: English does use deletions a lot. It is not always clear what the precise deletion is. I would say that it is not usually a matter of grammar - more one of style. I know that may not be a very precise explanation. Maybe it is worth a separate question; others may disagree with me!